# Weird decimal calculation in Java, potentially a bug?

Tags: java, math, decimal

I have weird decimal calculation that really surprise me, I have two big decimal number, one is a normal proce and the other one is an offer price. Then I want to calculate discount percentage and ceil it to the nearest integer.

Here are the code:

```
BigDecimal listPrice = new BigDecimal(510000);
BigDecimal offerPrice = new BigDecimal(433500);
int itemDiscount = (int)Math.ceil(((listPrice.longValue() - offerPrice.longValue()) / (float) listPrice.longValue()) * 100);
```

I expect it would set 15 as value of itemDiscount, but surprisingly it has 16, wow. Then i print each calculation to show in which statement is the problem, so i put System.out.println for each statement as below :

```
System.out.println(listPrice.longValue() - offerPrice.longValue()); //==> show 76500
System.out.println((listPrice.longValue() - offerPrice.longValue()) / (float) listPrice.longValue()); // ==> 0.15
System.out.println((listPrice.longValue() - offerPrice.longValue()) * 100 / (float) listPrice.longValue()); // ==> 15.000001
```

the problem is in above statement, istead of returning 15.0, it return 15.000001. And when i ceil it, it will of course return 16 instead of 15.

What is the explanation if this case? is this the way it is or it is a bug?

Comment: Ah, the beauty of floating point arithmetic.

Comment: The IEEE-754 strikes back.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo - It is not IEE-754's fault.  Every finite floating point representation suffers from problems with rounding errors at some point.

Comment: This another answer might help: [What causes floating-point rounding errors](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/101163/23837)

Comment: I'm with @user2310289.  You introduce `BigDecimal`, but you only ever use `.longValue()`.  If you want `BigDecimal`, then use its methods: `BigDecimal.subtract(BigDecimal)` and `BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal)`.  Then turn it into an `int`.  But first take the advice of @StephenC and figure out if you really need `ceil` instead of some other rounding method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the explanation if this case? is this the way it is or it is a bug?

It is the way it is.  It is not a bug.

You are doing the calculation using floating point types (`float`) and floating point arithmetic is imprecise.

I'm not sure what the best fix is here.  Maybe doing the computation using `BigDecimal` arithmetic methods would give a better result, but it is by no means guaranteed that you won't get similar problems in this calculation with different inputs ...

However, I suspect that the real problem is that you should not be using `ceil` in that calculation.  Even BigDecimal will give you rounding errors; e.g. if your computation involves dividing by 3, the intermediate result cannot be precisely represented using a base-10 representation.

The correct way to do calculations using Real numbers is to properly take account of the error bars in the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the divide method directly from the BigDecimal class.  If you are casting to a float then you are not using the benefit of BigDecimal .

http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-bigdecimal/bigDecimal-divide-int.shtml